# Try/Catch Wrap Around Task.Run not Handling Exception

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, task-parallel-library, task

I've been learning to use TPL and have an issue with an example I gathered from this [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/07/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-2.html). I copy and pasted the code exactly as in the Task.Run example but get an error message saying the exception isn't handled:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Hi!");
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here's a picture of the error:

[image]

Is this code example outdated or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to use `invoke()` but I am not sure

Comment: If you run this code not in a debugger, I suspect you'll find the message box gets shown - have you tried it? The exception isn't handled by code in the thread that's running the task, but you're catching it separately... I suspect the debugger is a little misleading here.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct. It works fine when not using the debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a misleading debugger message.

What's actually happening is that the exception is being thrown, then caught by the .NET framework (not user code), and then placed on the task.

So, while *technically* the error message is correct (it's caught by the .NET framework - unhandled by user code), it's not very helpful in this case.

Unfortunately, there's also not a lot of alternatives for the debugger. At the point when the exception leaves user code, the debugger has no way of "looking into the future" to know that the exception will be placed on a specific task and that your code will `await` that task. It has to make a decision immediately whether to notify you or not, without knowing whether the task will be `await`ed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s correct answer this happens only when the Debugger is on. Using this simple workaround you can re-throw the exception "outside" of Task.Run();

```
Exception exceptionOut = null;

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        // Your code
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionIn)
    {
        exceptionOut = exceptionIn;
    }
});

if (exceptionOut != null)
    throw exceptionOut;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your try/catch runs an async operation, thus does not hold the async operation, since the code is not guaranteed to be at that location when the exception is hit. Try including the try/catch within the `Task.Run(() => {..});`

Comment: The OP is awaiting the task within the try block, so the exception will be propagated and then caught. I suspect that "unhandled by user code" is a little imprecise here.