# Catch an async XML exception

Tags: xml, asynchronous, exception, async-await

This is my first time using async await and i'm using it to load large XML files. However, I cannot catch the XML exception errors. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
try
        {
            XElement element = await Task.Run(() => XElement.Load(filePath));

        }
        catch (System.Xml.XmlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Try catching Exception (not System.Xml.Exception), and set a breakpoint in the catch, then inspect the type of exception thrown.  A quick look at XmlReader.Create didn't show XmlException as one of the exceptions thrown.  Good luck.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Unfortunately, changing to Exception did not fix the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: What Exception type did the debugger reveal, when you step through the catch?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth apologies, you were correct. I also found an answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282414/try-catch-wrap-around-task-run-not-handling-exception)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for posting your solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to catch the exception with the following code. Also found at [Try/Catch Wrap Around Task.Run not Handling Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282414/try-catch-wrap-around-task-run-not-handling-exception).

```
try
        {
            Exception exceptionOut = null;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    XElement.Load(filePath);
                }
                catch (Exception exceptionIn)
                {
                    exceptionOut = exceptionIn;

                }
            });

            if (exceptionOut != null)
            {
                throw exceptionOut;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```